# LINQ sample: select typed objects from a list

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq

I have

```
Dim objectsList as List(Of Object) = GetAllObjects()

' Filter from Objects just Persons '
Dim peopleList as List(Of Person) = ???
```

What is the most efficient and effective LINQ expression to do it?

EDIT

```
1 Dim selectedObjects As List(Of Object) = GetAllObjects()
2 Dim selectedPeople As IEnumerable(Of Person)= selectedObjects.OfType(Of Person)
3 Dim people As List(Of Person) = selectedPeople.ToList()
```

Error on 3:

> Value of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List(Of
>   System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of Person))' cannot be
>   converted to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List(Of Person)'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you want [`Enumerable.OfType()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx):

```
Dim peopleList as List(Of Person) = objectsList.OfType(Of Person)().ToList()
```

Comment: in fact, you obtain an IEnumerable, not a List(Of), but pretty cool enough! ) Thank you )

Comment: @serhio the `ToList()` does that last step

Answer (score 1):

The most *effecient* approach is to filter at the point of origin (for example, at the point of database query, for example), not once we have the objects in memory, but:

```
Dim peopleList as List(Of Person) = objectsList.OfType(Of Person)().ToList()
```

or in C# (note this is identical once compiled):

```
var peopleList = objectsList.OfType<Person>().ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

In C# it would be

```
ObjectList.OfType<Person>()
```

VB .Net would be something similar